# How to show text from a website in a label

Tags: vb.net

I want to show the amount of followers i have on twitter.

```
<span class="DashboardProfileCard-statValue" data-is-compact="false">5,384</span>
```

I want the value "5,384" in my label. Help??

Comment: In what label did you want that string?

Comment: add an event whenever the value of your span is changed, and add this value to your label.

Answer (score 0):

I do stuff like this quite often.  Sorry, I'm not on twitter, but if that's the only place that "DashboardProfileCard-statValue"  appears in the HTML, this is what I'd do.

It would require refreshing the site, but you could put this under your browsers documentCompleted event

```
dim html as string = webbrowser1.document.body.innerhtml

For i = 0 to html.length - 1
    if mid(html, i, 30) = "DashboardProfileCard-statValue" Then
        msgbox(mid(html, i + 56, 5)
    End If
Next
```

That should (I think) show a messagebox of "5,384".  If it's like ">5,38" then just change the 56 to a 57.  Changing that number 56 will change what 5 characters you are displaying in a messagebox.